# How to update one dataframe based on the value of other dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have 2 dataframes in which I have to update the values based on the other dataframe-

Example:
df1:

```
Region   Sub_Region   Status    Reason
LATAM    CRM          Success 
LATAM    Genesys      Failed
ASPAC    CRM          Success
ASPAC    Genesys      Success
```

df2:

```
Region  Sub_Region  Max_Load_Date
LATAM   CRM         2021-08-15
LATAM   Genesys     2021-09-10
ASPAC   CRM         2021-10-11
ASPAC   Genesys     2021-10-15
```

In Final Output:

```
Region   Sub_Region   Status   Reason   Max_Load_Date
LATAM    CRM          Success           2021-08-15
LATAM    Genesys      Failed
ASPAC    CRM          Success           2021-10-11
ASPAC    Genesys      Success           2021-10-15
```

Only those will update for which status = 'Success'

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` and `mask`:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on=['Region', 'Sub_Region'])
    .assign(Max_Load_Date=lambda d: d['Max_Load_Date'].mask(d['Status']=='Failed', ''))
)
```

Merging will ensure the correct data is mapped to the correct row in case both dataframes are not sorted in the exact same order or have missing rows.

output:

```
  Region Sub_Region   Status Max_Load_Date
0  LATAM        CRM  Success    2021-08-15
1  LATAM    Genesys   Failed              
2  ASPAC        CRM  Success    2021-10-11
3  ASPAC    Genesys  Success    2021-10-15
```

Comment: Getting error-
ValueError: 'Region' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.